# Spring Data Jpa - ManyToMany - delete entities of the join table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have these two classes :

```
public class ClassA extends [...] implements [...] {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = JOIN_TABLE_NAME,
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_REF_A, referencedColumnName = COLUMN_ID_A),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_REF_B, referencedColumnName = COLUMN_ID_B))
    private List<ClassB> fieldClassB;   
}

public class ClassB extends [...] implements [...] {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fieldClassB", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ClassA> fieldClassA;

}
```

When I delete `ClassB` (via the spring data jpa repository), Hibernate also deletes instances of `ClassA`, whereas I just want the rows in the `JOIN_TABLE_NAME` table to be deleted (the other issue is that, due to the cascade mode, deleting the `ClassA` entities also delete other `ClassB` referenced by these `ClassA`).

Is there any way to handle this without having to create the join entity and to replace the `@ManyToMany` annotations by `@OneToMany` referencing the new join entity ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cascade Remove in a manyToMany it's not only applied to the link table, but to the other side of the association as well.

So Cascade.ALL which inherit remove too is almost always a bad thing to have on a manyToMany as it ends up deleting things not only from association table.

What you want is to have add and remove method in your entities to do the work and keep both list synchronized:

```
public class ClassA extends [...] implements [...] {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = JOIN_TABLE_NAME,
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_REF_A, referencedColumnName = COLUMN_ID_A),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_REF_B, referencedColumnName = COLUMN_ID_B))
    private List<ClassB> fieldClassB; 

    public void addClassB(ClassB b) {
        fieldClassB.add(b);
        b.fieldClassA().add(this);
    }

    public void removeClassB(ClassB b) {
        fieldClassB.remove(b);
        b.fieldClassA().remove(this);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you Zeromus. This is effectively the piece of the puzzle I was missing. I've bound the remove operation to a method annotated with `@PreRemove` (in `ClassB`) to automatically handle the operation.

Comment: @Thoomas How did you manage to implement this remove function with the `@PreRemove` annotation? When I try it I get a compile error `Callback methods annotated on the bean class must return void and take no arguments: javax.persistence.PreRemove`

Comment: @Mahan_F `ClassB` has a method with this signature : `@PreRemove public void preRemove() { ... }`