# Hibernate Data Integrity Violation Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, repository

I have a many to many relation between **Permission** and **Role** classes. 
And there is a **role_permission** table to keep relation between role and permission

```
CREATE TABLE public.role_permissions
(
  role_id bigint NOT NULL,
  permission_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT role_permissions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (role_id, permission_id),
  CONSTRAINT fkh0v7u4w7mttcu81o8wegayr8e FOREIGN KEY (permission_id)
      REFERENCES public.permission (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fklodb7xh4a2xjv39gc3lsop95n FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
      REFERENCES public.role (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.role_permissions
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I want to delete Permission it throws following error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "permission" violates foreign key constraint "fkh0v7u4w7mttcu81o8wegayr8e" on table "role_permissions"
  Detail: Key (id)=(6) is still referenced from table "role_permissions".
```

Here is my class implementations

```
package com.nova.stats.client.backend.auth.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.PreRemove;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"users", "roles"})
@ToString(exclude = {"users", "roles"})
@Entity
public class Permission implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max=100, message = "Permission name must be between {min} and {max} characters long")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max=250, message = "Permission description must be between {min} and {max} characters long")
    @Column
    private String description;

    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@Override))
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 6, max=100, message = "Permission authority must be between {min} and {max} characters long")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String authority;

    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions")
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions")
    private Set<User> users;

    public Permission(String name, String description, String authority) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.authority = authority;
    }
}



package com.nova.stats.client.backend.auth.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"users", "permissions"})
@ToString(exclude = {"users", "permissions"})
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max=100, message = "Role name must be between {min} and {max} characters long")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max=250, message = "Role description must be between {min} and {max} characters long")
    @Column
    private String description;

    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@Override))
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 6, max=100, message = "Role authority must be between {min} and {max} characters long")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String authority;

    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
    @Setter(onMethod = @__(@JsonProperty("permissions")))
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_permissions", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Permission> permissions;

    public Role(String name, String description, String authority, Set<Permission> permissions) {
        this(name, description, authority);
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public Role(String name, String description, String authority) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.authority = authority;
    }
}
```

Here is what I need; when I want to delete any permission then foreign key must be deleted in **role_permission** table but related **role** can't be delete. I mean when delete permission, just delete permission on table **permission** and relation on table **role_permission**

What should I do for that ?

Comment: you must remove the Permission object reference from the Role too.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419158/spring-data-jpa-manytomany-delete-entities-of-the-join-table)

Comment: Why don't you change your foreign key (permission_id) to be ON DELETE CASCADE?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when try to delete a permission, it is still referenced on user. You need to delete the user first or remove it's permission before removing from permission table.

To delete in cascade you can try this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "permissions")
private Set<User> users;
```

Answer (score 0):

I added "@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)" annotation on **User** and **Permission** in **Role class**
And also added **Role** and **User** in **Permission class**
And now, It works as I want

Here is an Example

```
package com.asd.asd;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"users", "roles"})
@ToString(exclude = {"users", "roles"})
@Entity
public class Permission implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max=100, message = "Permission name must be between {min} and {max} characters long")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max=250, message = "Permission description must be between {min} and {max} characters long")
    @Column
    private String description;

    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@Override))
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 6, max=100, message = "Permission authority must be between {min} and {max} characters long")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String authority;

    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<User> users;

    public Permission(String name, String description, String authority) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.authority = authority;
    }
}
```