# How should I remove data from Join table in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I was trying to create a Library management system for that I have created two entities `Student` and `Books`both are connected using the `@ManytoMany` relation so I had used another join table where I store the Id of the book and Id of the student when a student Issues a book from Library but when the student returns the book the row contains both the ID's in the join table should be deleted but When I am trying to do so Either all the data from the Join table get deleted or my student and book got deleted
Here is my code for that Please suggest to me what I am doing wrong here and what should be the best practice

**Student Entity**

```
package com.Library.LibraryManagement.Entity;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="student_email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="student_course")
    private Integer course;
    @Column(name="date_of_birth")
    private String dateOfBirth;
    @Column(name="student_status")
    private Integer status;
    @Column(name="added_at")
    private Timestamp addedAt;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="student_books",
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="books_id"))
    private List<Books> books;
    
    
    public Student() {
    //Empty Constructor 
    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email, Integer course,String dateOfBirth,Integer status,Timestamp addedAt) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.course = course;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.status = status;
        this.addedAt = addedAt;
    }

    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Integer course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
    
    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Timestamp getAddedAt() {
        return addedAt;
    }

    public void setAddedAt(Timestamp addedAt) {
        this.addedAt = addedAt;
    }

    public List<Books> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Books> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
    
    public void removeBook(Books boo) {
        this.books.remove(boo);
        boo.getStudents().remove(this);
    }

    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"id\":\"" + id + "\", \"firstName\":\"" + firstName + "\", \"lastName\":\"" + lastName
                + "\", \"email\":\"" + email + "\", \"course\":\"" + course + "\", \"dateOfBirth\":\"" + dateOfBirth
                + "\", \"status\":\"" + status + "\", \"addedAt\":\"" + addedAt + "\"}";
    }

}
```

**Books Entity**

```
package com.Library.LibraryManagement.Entity;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Books {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="book_name")
    private String bookName;
    @Column(name="book_publisher")
    private String bookPublisherName;
    @Column(name="book_description")
    private String bookDescription;
    @Column(name="book_language")
    private String bookLanguage;
    @Column(name="book_in_stock")
    private Integer bookInStock;
    @Column(name="added_at")
    private Timestamp addedAt;
    @Column(name="deleted")
    private Integer deleted;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="student_books",
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "books_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_id"))
    private List<Student> students;
    
    public Books() {
        
    }
    
    public Books(String bookName, String bookPublisherName, String bookDescription, String bookLanguage,Timestamp addedAt,
            Integer bookInStock,Integer deleted) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.bookPublisherName = bookPublisherName;
        this.bookDescription = bookDescription;
        this.bookLanguage = bookLanguage;
        this.bookInStock = bookInStock;
        this.addedAt =addedAt;
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public String getBookPublisherName() {
        return bookPublisherName;
    }

    public void setBookPublisherName(String bookPublisherName) {
        this.bookPublisherName = bookPublisherName;
    }

    public String getBookDescription() {
        return bookDescription;
    }

    public void setBookDescription(String bookDescription) {
        this.bookDescription = bookDescription;
    }

    public String getBookLanguage() {
        return bookLanguage;
    }

    public void setBookLanguage(String bookLanguage) {
        this.bookLanguage = bookLanguage;
    }

    public Integer getBookInStock() {
        return bookInStock;
    }

    public void setBookInStock(Integer bookInStock) {
        this.bookInStock = bookInStock;
    }
    
    public Timestamp getAddedAt() {
        return addedAt;
    }

    public void setAddedAt(Timestamp addedAt) {
        this.addedAt = addedAt;
    }

    public Integer getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(Integer deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
    
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
    
    
    public void removeBook(Student stu) {
        this.students.remove(stu);
        stu.getBooks().remove(this);
    }
    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"id\":\"" + id + "\", \"bookName\":\"" + bookName + "\", \"bookPublisherName\":\"" + bookPublisherName
                + "\", \"bookDescription\":\"" + bookDescription + "\", \"bookLanguage\":\"" + bookLanguage
                + "\", \"bookInStock\":\"" + bookInStock + "\", \"addedAt\":\"" + addedAt + "\", \"deleted\":\""
                + deleted + "\"}";
    }
    
    //Convience MEthods to help with adding the student
    public void addStudent(Student theStudent) {
        if(students ==null) {
            students = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        students.add(theStudent);
    }
}
```

**Method used to Revome Data from Join table**

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void returnBok(Student student, Books book) {
        try {
            if(student !=null && book !=null) {
//              Student stu = book.getStudents(.); 
//                  book.removeBook(student);
                for(Books books : student.getBooks()) {
                    student.removeBook(book);
                }
                entityManage.remove(student);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data Jpa - ManyToMany - delete entities of the join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419158/spring-data-jpa-manytomany-delete-entities-of-the-join-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using `entityManager.remove`. That command will delete a student and all the books associated to it because of the cascade.

If you only want to remove a book from the association,the `returnBook` method should look something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void returnBook(Student student, Books book) {
    try {
         if(student !=null && book !=null) {
             Student entityStudent = entityManager.getReference( Student.class, student.getId())
             Book entityBook = entityManager.getReference( Book.class, book.getId())
             entityStudent.removeBook(entityBook);
        }
    }
...
}
```

Changes will be propagated to the db during commit or the flush of the session.

Note that I've added the `getReference()` calls because I don't know if `student` and `book` are managed entities. If they are, it's not necessary to use `getReference()`.

Assuming that this is what `removeBook` looks like:

```
    public void removeBook(Book book) {
        this.books.remove( book );
        book.getStudents().remove( this );
    }
```

As described [in the Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional), it's important to update both side of the association.

Also the mapping of the association on one of the entities should be:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "...")
```

You should decide which entity owns the association.

By the way, are you sure the mapping you are trying to achieve is not the one described in the Hibernate ORM documentation as `Example 172. Bidirectional many-to-many with link entity`?

Comment: I have updated my annotation as on student entity `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students") private List<Books> books;` and on Book entity it remains the same as `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)  @JoinTable(name="student_books",     joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "books_id"),     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_id"))  private List<Student> students;` But nowI am getting `Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'studentId' for method parameter type Integer is not present]` error

Comment: That doesn't seem a mapping problem. It seems that a parameter is missing, don't you require a `studentId` parameter somewhere?

Comment: It seems that an http call to the servlet doesn't pass the parameter `studentId`

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/ReturnBook" , method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
 public String returnBook(@RequestParam("bookId") Integer bookId,HttpSession session) {
  Books book = null;
  Student student = null;
  try {
   if(bookId !=null) {
    book = bookService.getBookByID(bookId);
    student = (Student) session.getAttribute("thisStudent");
    LOGGER.info("BOOK : " + book);    
    LOGGER.info("Student : " + student);    
    studentService.returnBok(student, book);
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return "String";
 }`

Comment: this is the controller I get the student from the session

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107570/exception-org-springframework-web-bind-missingservletrequestparameterexception#37316201

Answer (score 2):

Your many-to-many relationship is not mapped correctly.

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html) says this:

> Every many-to-many association has two sides, the owning side and the
> non-owning, or inverse, side. **The join table is specified on the
> owning side**. If the association is bidirectional, either side may be
> designated as the owning side. **If the relationship is bidirectional,
> the non-owning side must use the `mappedBy` element** of the `ManyToMany`
> annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the owning
> side.

(emphasis added).

Your annotations map the relationship as if both sides owned it, which is incorrect.

Once you choose an owning side, you modify the relationship by updating the relationship field on the owning side and saving the modified owning entity.  You have other answers showing how to do that.  You probably want also to either make corresponding changes to the non-owning side or to refresh the non-owning entity to bring the relationship field on that side into sync.

Comment: I have updated my annotation as on student entity `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
private List<Books> books;`
and on Book entity it remains the same as `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
 @JoinTable(name="student_books",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "books_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_id"))
 private List<Student> students;` But nowI am getting `Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'studentId' for method parameter type Integer is not present]` error

Comment: @shivamsharma, I see no reason to think that the exception you are now getting is related to the correction to the entity mapping.  No methods should have been added, removed, or modified as part of the annotation change.  In fact, it looks like the exception might reflect a client-side error, but I haven't the context to be sure.

Comment: after the update of student entity `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students") private List<Books> books;` I found now I am able to link the student to a book but not able to remove book and student from the join table which was my main concern is there something with the cascade ??

Comment: @shivamsharma, updating the join table in response to modifications to the relationship attribute has nothing to do with cascading.  Supposing that the mapping is declared correctly, that's just the normal JPA behavior for managing the relationship (via the entity on the owning side).  That procedure is described in this answer, and in more detail in other answers.

Comment: It's fixed now the issue was with removebok method thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It sohuld be

```
student.getBooks().remove(book);

entityManger.save(student)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using your method of returnBooke use this :

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void returnBok(Student student, Books book) {
        try {
            if (student != null && book != null) {
                student.getBooks().removeIf(books -> {
                    return Objects.equals(book.getId(), books.getId());
                });
                entityManager.save(student);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Because in above method you are removing whole student object `entityManage.remove(student);` , thats why your student is delete and due to
 `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in the mapping your book object is also deleted.

One more suggestion. Instead of populating Getter, Setter and Constructor.

Use Lombok plugin :

https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide